# Include images as Inline in sass without Compass?

Tags: css, sass

I want to add images as base64 in sass. I have been locking at Compass but it feels way to bulky and really not what I'm looking for. Is there a good way to include images or other files inline in css without using compass?

Comment: You could, you know, just use Compass.  On its own, it is no "bulkier" than Sass:  you get simpler command line in exchange for using a config file.  You don't have to do any importing to get access to any of the helper functions:  http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/

Comment: @cimmanon - if you use pure sass, then you can use libsass, which is miles faster than ruby sass, this can be a good reason not to use compass

Comment: @callum libsass also doesn't compile certain things properly and lags behind the official Sass in terms of feature support.  https://github.com/hcatlin/libsass/issues/282

Comment: yep, but a lot of people are using it, because it's close enough to ruby sass, and the performance benefit is huge

Answer (score 3):

If you use grunt, you can just use the [grunt-data-uri](https://github.com/ahomu/grunt-data-uri) task in order to achieve the conversation of regular url() string to base64.

```
        dataUri: {
           dist: {
              src: ['dist/styles/*.css'],
              dest: 'dist/styles/',
              options: {
                target: [
                    'img/low-res/embeded/*.*'
                ],
                fixDirLevel: true
              }
          }
       },
```

Essentially, the task will look for every images contained inside the embeded folder in your .css. From there, it will convert the url() into base64.

Answer (score 1):

Compass is Open Source, just get the part of the code that suit you.

[Here is the ruby source on Github](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/stable/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/inline_image.rb)

Comment: Well, just run `base64 your-image.png` on shell

Comment: That looks pretty out-of-the-box though... I'm not very experienced in ruby... how would I get it running...

Comment: Unfortunately, if you use `node-sass` written in C, copying ruby code around is not a solution...